# How to Update column values of T1 from T2 using one condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried this query and i get this msg SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ,but i can't see where the problem realy is ?

```
update T1 set T1.name=T2.name from Table1 T1
inner join Table2 T2
on T1.id=T2.id where T2.id in (select id from Table2   group by  id having  count(entity)=1);
```

Comment: Does Oracle really support that UPDATE FROM syntax?

Comment: Doesn't look like the syntax is correct according to the docs I found, not that it isn't `ended` correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement is not valid Oracle syntax.

You have two common options.

Option #1: use a correlated subquery in your `UPDATE`...

```
update table t1
set    t1.name = ( SELECT t2.name
                   FROM   table2 t2
                   WHERE  t2.id = t1.id 
                   AND    t2.id IN ( SELECT t2a.id 
                                     FROM table2 t2a 
                                     GROUP BY t2a.id 
                                     HAVING COUNT(t2a.entity) = 1 )
                 ) 
where exists ( SELECT 'x'
               FROM   table2 t2
               WHERE  t2.id = t1.id 
               AND    t2.id IN ( SELECT t2a.id 
                                 FROM table2 t2a 
                                 GROUP BY t2a.id 
                                 HAVING COUNT(t2a.entity) = 1 )
```

;

Option #2: (my preference) use a `MERGE` statement:

```
merge into table1 t
using  ( SELECT t2.id, 
                t2.name,
                COUNT(t2.entity) OVER ( PARTITION BY t2.id ) entity_count
         FROM   table2 t2
       ) u
ON ( t.id = u.id AND u.entity_count = 1 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.name = u.name;
```

I usually test SQL before I post it, but no time today.  So, there might be syntax errors in the above.

Comment: The `update` version is not correct.  It will set non-matching names to `null`, which the OP's version would not (in a database that supports that syntax).

Comment: To avoid updating not matching names i added to the first query:  where exists  (select 1 from table2 t2 ......)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase the `update` as:

```
update table t1
    set t1.name = (select t2.name
                   from table2 t2
                   where t2.id = t1.id and rownum = 1
                  )
    where (select count(t2.entity)
           from table2 t2
           where t2.id = t1.id
          ) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the data context. I created an example where ID's aren't UNIQUE

```
create table T1 ( name varchar2(55), id number(4,0), entity number(2,0));
create table T2 ( name varchar2(55), id number(4,0), entity number(2,0));

insert into T1 (name, id, entity) values ('T1name1', 1, 1);
insert into T1 (name, id, entity) values ('T1name2', 2, 1);
insert into T1 (name, id, entity) values ('T1name3', 3, 3);
insert into T1 (name, id, entity) values ('T1name4', 4, 4);

insert into T2 (name, id, entity) values ('T2name1', 1, 1);
insert into T2 (name, id, entity) values ('T2name2', 2, 1);
insert into T2 (name, id, entity) values ('T2name3', 3, 3);
insert into T2 (name, id, entity) values ('T2name4', 3, 1);

update T1 set name =
                    nvl(
                        ( select name
                          from T2
                          where T2.id = T1.id 
                            and exists 
                                ( select 'x'  
                                  from T2 table2 
                                  where table2.id = T2.id
                                  group by id 
                                  having count(entity) = 1)
                         )
                    ,T1.name)
```

In this context, just T1.id = 1 and T1.id = 2 will be updated (T2.id = 3 has count(entity) = 2)